# How to get @user.posts in a view by date in decending order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a user show view. @user has a :wall that has many :posts. how to I return @user.wall.posts by date?

Theses wall.posts can be from @user or other users.

FYI I am learning rails by making a Facebook clone.

view

```
<% @user.wall.posts.each do |post| %>
    <div class="status">
        <h3><%= link_to post.author.name %></h3>
        <h4><%= post.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %></h4>
        <p><%= post.content %></p>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

controller

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @post = Post.new
end
```

Please point out anything I'm doing wrong if theres a better way to handle something like this.

Answer (score 3):

You can get [ordered](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering) posts like this:

```
@user.wall.posts.order(created_at: :desc)
```

This is a bit dirty in the view though, so you can declare a [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) in `Post`:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_date, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
end
```

Then use it in your view:

```
@user.wall.posts.by_date
```

If you always want `Wall` to return posts ordered by date, you can [declare the association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-many) like this:

```
class Wall < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, -> { by_date }
end
```

Note that the above example uses the scope in `Post` as well.

Answer (score 1):

This should work in your posts model

```
default_scope { order("created_at DESC")}
```

You can find more information [ActiveRecord::Scoping::Default::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html)

This will make all posts display desc dependent on the post date.